# How do I make two UIButtons perform like radio buttons in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift3, uibutton, radio-button

I have two `UIButton`s that I want to use to set an A/B value to a variable before I save data to a database. I want a button to become selected when tapped, and deselected when the other button is tapped, and vice versa. What is a good solution for accomplishing this programmatically or in Interface Builder?

Comment: Consider `UISegmentedControl`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to set an "A/B value" as you mention, the easiest option would be to use a `UISwitch` or -in the general case of possibly more than 2 options- a `UISegmentedControl` (as @rmaddy suggested in the question's comments) .

These controls have built-in the "choose just one out of many" functionality that you are looking for.

The drawbacks of the switch are:

- It has to be either on or off (does not support a selection state of "neither A nor B")
- You can't have separate title labels for each state.

---

If you still want two separate `UIButton` instances, you can:

- Have references to both buttons in your view controller (`@IBOutlet`s wired using Interface Builder), e.g.:

  ```
  @IBOutlet weak var leftButton: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var rightButton: UIButton!
  ```
- Implement the action method for both buttons in such a way that it sets the selected state of the tapped button, and resets the other one. For example:

  ```
  @IBAction func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {
      if sender == leftButton {
          leftButton.isSelected = true
          rightButton.isSelected = false
      } else if sender == rightButton{
          leftButton.isSelected = false
          rightButton.isSelected = true
      }
  }
  ```

This is a quick-and-dirty solution for just two buttons. If you want a generic **radio group** of n-buttons, there are open source solutions on GitHub, etc...

Answer (score 1):

**Try this.**

First create both button separate @IBOutlet.

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnYes: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnNo: UIButton!
```

Set Both Button Tag Like this and you also set tag using storyboard.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

    btnYes.tag = 1
    btnNo.tag = 2
}
```

Implement Common @IBAction method for both buttons

```
@IBAction func btnYesNoTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.tag == 1 {
            self.IsBtnSelected(isSelect: true, with: self.btnYes)
        }else {
            self.IsBtnSelected(isSelect: true, with: self.btnNo)
        }

}
```

Create Custome Method

```
func IsBtnSelected(isSelect:Bool,with sender:UIButton){
        self.btnYes.isSelected = false
        self.btnNo.isSelected = false
        sender.isSelected = isSelect
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like below

I have implemented it for dates which are in `TableView` you just need to do little modifications

```
enum filterDateSelectableOptions:Int {
    case AssignDate
    case DueDate
    case CompletionDate

}
//Assign Date selected by default 
var currentSelectedFilterDate:filterDateSelectableOptions = .AssignDate
```

Now

```
func btnRadioButtonTapped(sender:UIButton) {

    switch sender.tag {
    case kTableViewRow.AssignDate.rawValue:
        self.currentSelectedFilterDate = .AssignDate

    case kTableViewRow.DueDate.rawValue:
        self.currentSelectedFilterDate = .DueDate

    case kTableViewRow.CompletionDate.rawValue :
        self.currentSelectedFilterDate = .CompletionDate
    default:
        break;
    }
    //sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    self.tblFilterList.reloadData()
}
```

in `cellForRow` I have

```
          // THIS IS DIFFERENT ENUM SO +1 is required in my case
     case .AssignDate,.DueDate,.CompletionDate :
        let button = buttonRadioCircle
        button.tag = row.rawValue
        cell.accessoryView = button
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnRadioButtonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)


        button.isSelected = self.currentSelectedFilterDate.rawValue + 1 == row.rawValue
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following function for creating a radio button behaviour, you have to btn outlet to be selected and array of both outlets to this function. instead ofcolor you can also compare images and set images. for getting a required value yo can create a variable in viewcontroller and assign this variable a value in IBAction of btn and you can call this function from IBAction.

```
func radioButton(_ btnToBeSelected: UIButton, _ btnArray: [UIButton]) {
    for btn in btnArray {
        if btn == btnToBeSelected {
            btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            //selected btn
            //You can also set btn images by 
            //btn.setImage(<#T##image: UIImage?##UIImage?#>, for: <#T##UIControlState#>)
        } else {
            btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            //not selected btn
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS , you would have to do it manually.See the below approaches,

1. Use a switch . Using a UISwitch would be better if the option indicates a on/off state.
2. Use a same method when the button is pressed. Whenever the method gets called deselect the other button/buttons and select the pressed button. You can use tags or keep a reference of the buttons to differentiate between them.
3. Lastly , keep different methods for each buttons . Just deselect the other buttons whenever the button is pressed.

You can follow the above approaches by using interface builder or programmatically.